# Map() and dplyr joins

Tags: r, dplyr, mapply

I have two lists, both of which contain similar datasets corresponding to different years. I wish to merge the datasets in both lists, element by element. When I use `mapply`, alongside `dplyr::full_join`, in the instance where the variable names don't match and I need to use the `by` argument, R is unable to perform the join.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)

first_list <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = rnorm(3)), 
                   data.frame(x = 4:6, y = rnorm(3)))

second_list <- list(data.frame(z = 1:3, w = rnorm(3)), 
                    data.frame(z = 4:6, w = rnorm(3)))

Map(full_join, by = c("x" = "z"), first_list, second_list)
#Error: 'z' column not found in rhs, cannot join
```

However,

```
Map(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = c("x" = "z")), first_list, second_list)
```

works successfully. I am curious about this behaviour and wonder if anyone could provide some explanation.

Comment: The dplyr family of packages rewrites Map, mapply, et al (as map, map2, and others, I think). If you really want to use those, you might want to read up on the "grammar" hadley defined for lists: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Map` is a wrapper to `mapply`, use its *MoreArgs* argument while the other required args (...) include lists to be vectorized over (see `?mapply`):

```
test1 <- Map(full_join, first_list, second_list, MoreArgs=list(by = c("x" = "z")))

test2 <- Map(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = c("x" = "z")), first_list, second_list)

all.equal(test1, test2)
# [1] TRUE
```